# NavigationBar large title not collapse when I have custom image/view under tableView iOS 13

Tags: swift, navigationbar, ios13, large-title, preferslargetitles

I have an issue with collapsing navigation bar with `largeTitles` enabled. Basically if there is nothing under the table view, everything is working fine. Once I am adding a default image under the table view, scroll is working on table view, but large navigation bar is stuck in large position.

Any idea for this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long search and a lot of tries, finally I figure out in a different way:

`tblSettings.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImageName"))`

Setting `backgroundView` to `UITableView` it will allow navigation bar to animate properly to large and normal titles.

Hope this will someone!